# How to find the MLE of the mean of Gamma distribution

Tags: statistics, estimation

If I parameterize Gamma distribution in the way as $\Gamma(\alpha,\frac{\mu}{\alpha})$, am I able to find the maximum likelihood estimator of $\mu$. Here, $\alpha$ is the shape parameter, $\frac{\mu}{\alpha}$ is the scale parameter, and $\mu$ is the mean of 
Gamma distribution.

Comment: Have you tried wiki?: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Maximum_likelihood_estimation

Comment: I think I probably found the answer:

The pdf of $\Gamma(\alpha,\frac{\mu}{\alpha})$ is: 
$\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)(\frac{\mu}{\alpha})^\alpha}x^{\alpha-1}e^{\frac{-\alpha x}{\mu}}$

$\ell(\alpha,\mu)=(\alpha-1)\Sigma_{i=1}^N ln(x_i) - \Sigma_{i=1}^N \frac{x_i\alpha}{\mu} -N\alpha ln(\frac{\mu}{\alpha})-Nln(\Gamma(k))$

set $\frac{\partial\ell}{\partial \mu} = \Sigma_{i=1}^N x_i\alpha \frac{1}{\mu^2}-N\alpha\frac{\alpha}{\mu}\frac{1}{\alpha} = 0$

$\hat{\mu} = \bar{X}$

Comment: @d.k.o. hey,dude. If YOU looked at wiki, you would find wiki just have the mle of rate and scale parameter

Comment: Yes, but you can convert their parametrization ($\Gamma(\alpha,\theta)$) into yours ($\Gamma(\alpha, \mu/\alpha)$) so that $\hat\mu=\hat\theta \alpha=\bar X$

Comment: @d.k.o. Thank you for your comments. But I am not sure if you can simply convert. Because when I tried to convert wiki's parameterization of Negative Binomial$(p,r)$ into $NB(\mu,\alpha)$ and tried to find the mle of $\mu$ and $\alpha$, it didn't work that way. $\mu$ is mean and $\alpha$ is the overdispersion parameter

Comment: Can you tell us like what is your Gamma pdf? Because different book, different notation.

Comment: $\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)(\frac{\mu}{\alpha})^\alpha}x^{\alpha-1}e^{\frac{-\alpha x}{\mu}}$